# What is the advantage of property attributes "feature" in ECMAScript-5?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I want to know more about usage of property attributes described here: 
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.1

I can imagine usecases of these attributes, but they are very rare. 
In addition writable, enumerable and configurable properties are set to false by default, but mostly I want to have these values **true**, so I have to set them. Why are they false by default?

Make object and set its attributes was very basic thing for me. Now there is property descriptor, which I could describe like artificial, unnatural, complicated or uncomfortable. Maybe I just missed something very essential.

So my questions are: **What is main purpose of property attributes. How can we use them?**

**Can I avoid using property descriptor? For example with some good pattern that will set attributes for me?** For example if I use Object.create with second param "Properties", it forces me to use property descriptor. So should I avoid to use this?

Comment: "*Can I avoid property descriptors*" - of course, there's nothing that forces you to use them. Just do old-school property assignment.

Comment: I don't know why they made the default `false`, but I'd guess it's because there's already a way to make properties with a default of `true`. What's your actual concern? If you want some custom behavior WRT the defaults, just create a function that sets the defaults however you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"...mostly I want to have these values true, so I have to set them."*

Only if you have a need for them. If you don't, then just use the typical object literal syntax, or the assignment operator for new properties.

> *"Why are they false by default?"*

I would imagine it's because there's already a syntax available that defaults them to `true`.

> *"Make object and set its attributes was very basic thing for me. Now there is property descriptor...*"

Nothing has changed. It's just as basic as it was before. There are simply more tools at your disposal if you need them.

> *"...which I could describe like artificial, unnatural, complicated or uncomfortable."*

The syntax is perhaps a little cumbersome, but if you don't like it, don't use it. If you need to set the property descriptors to something other than `true`, then I would think you'd be glad to have the new capabilities, irrespective of its syntax.

Also, there's likely property descriptor definition being added to object literal syntax in ECMAScript 6.

> *"So my questions are: What is main purpose of property attributes. How can we use them?"*

That should be self-explanatory. They're for manually configuring the `configurable`, `writeable`, and `enumerable` settings of properties on an object. If you ever come across a situation where you need one of those settings, you'll use them.

> *"Can I avoid using property descriptor?"*

Of course. Again, nothing has changed. They're there if you need them. If you don't, then ignore them.

> *"For example with some good pattern that will set attributes for me?"*

Not sure what you mean, but if you want different defaults, just use a helper function, like:

```
function addWriteable(obj, prop, value) {
    return Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
        writeable: true
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default for writeable is `false` only if

> If the value of an attribute is not explicitly specified by this specification for a named property

For properties you define by hand it will be `true` for example. The thing you should be aware of that there is a huge difference between ecmascript itself without any specification on top of it and the javascript/jscript dialects.

Either way, in general you should never do anything with these attribute properties, except if you're considering making a framework or anything along those lines. For example, prototype.js could use it to set `Enumerable` to `false` and I used it myself to redefine the `Get` to allow a bit of an exotic syntax which was easier for developers to use (similar to a different native syntax), but whilst doing normal stuff you don't need it.

Comment: Object.create with two parameters call defineProperties which force me to use property descriptor. So does your answer implie that I should avoid using "properties" parameter declaration in this function? Because otherwise I think I should understand things that I am setting.

Comment: Indeed, don't set anything if you don't need to.